# Как вы выбираете значение из справочника при заполнении формы?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

*изучаю MVC, и сейчас очень интересует как лучше всего выбирать значения из большого справочника?... я уже научился связывать сущность с выпадающим списком но мне не нравится, что весь справочник отправляется в представление...*

Кто не жадный поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим кодом? вернее частью кода, ключевые моменты модели, представления и поведения... главное чтобы была возможность ввода символов и на возврате был код а не название из справочника...

**Заранее огромное Спасибо!**

Comment: >главное чтобы была возможность ввода символов и на возврате был код а не название из справочника...

Пардон?

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/PXBOunl.jpg

Comment: уточню... чтобы в контроллер вернулся Id а не наименование справочника.
как вариант, представляю себе два способа: первый это текстовое поле с выпадающими вариантами (но у меня не получилось вернуть Id); второй это когда открывается div и в нем структурированный справочник с фильтрами (мне пока кажется это сложным... очень много JavaScript'a)
возможно есть и другие практичные варианты... буду рад любой подсказке...

Comment: Ну вообще это довольно просто. Если вы отправляете данные в Action с помощью постинга формы, то привязка модели все сделает за вас (во всяком случае с обычным выпадающим списком). Если же вы используете ajax, то вам просто следует указать, что именно нужно отправлять на сервер. Небольшой пример с JQuery:

    $.ajax({
       url: 'your url here',
       data: { id: $('#myDropDown').val() }
       .......
    });

 А вы как пытаетесь это делать?

Comment: ajax я пока не использовал... но пытался делать как тут: http://www.gotdotnet.ru/blogs/razon/4871/
но на выходе не разобрался как получить id выбранного варианта(... это пытался сделать для ввода города, но нашел другой способ с тремя DropDownList'ами... но уже скоро дойдет очередь создавать возможность выбора из справочников предприятий, там это не пройдет, нужен предварительный фильтр...

Comment: Я новичок-самоучка, собираю информацию по крупицам, в отдельности вроде бы все понятно, но соединить очень трудно, ну... возможно только для меня)... я придумал проект и под него специально изучаю MVC и постепенно, хоть и маленькими шагами, я реализую его! в основном программисты используют свои стили программирования... если что-то нужно сделать... то есть какая-то своя заготовка... она берется и переделывается под новую задачу... у меня нет опыта и нет оттестированной заготовки, поэтому я и клянчу чтобы кто-то поделился (читайте вопрос) - мне нужен чужой опыт, это сэкономит кучу времени)

Comment: @KrutVladimir ну так вроде бы в той статье (которую я все-таки смог открыть) все более-менее понятно описано, и даже прилагается пример, в чем сложность-то?

Comment: ну да... работает! но я не смог получить id из справочника... там предлагаются варианты для string (textBox) но мне нужно в конце, да и в любой момент времени определить Id выбранного варианта

Comment: Используйте JavaScript или JQuery, пример выше я вам показывал